# bookdown include other .md files

Tags: r, bookdown

I am about to begin writing my thesis, and am planning on using Bookdown with .Rmd files to achieve this.

However, the way bookdown searches for content isn't exactly what I want. As my thesis will be long, filled with many individual chapters and subchapters, I don't want to be restricted on having hundreds of .Rmd files in the root directory.

Instead, what I would like to do is have main chapters as .Rmd files, with a header designated by #, but then be able to "include" sub .md/.Rmd files from a folder. This way I can keep my thesis organised and easily be able to change the order of sections, but also not have to put a top level header at the top of every page.

What I'd like to do:

- /
- /content/introduction/chapter1.md
- 00-introduction.Rmd
- 01-somesection.Rmd

Then in 00-introduction.Rmd be able to call the subpages freely (in this case /content/introduction/chapter1.md, but of course there could be dozens of such chapters).

I noticed that this does exist for Pandoc for example: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-include

Is this possible in Bookdown?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible to have folders, sub-folders, etc. as described [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/configuration.html) and [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/usage.html#usage), either defined within an index with `rmd_files` or sub-folders with `rmd_subdir`.

For example, for my thesis I am presently writing, I use the following structure in a seperate `_bookdown.yml` file in the root folder:

```
book_filename: "bookdown"
new_session: no # merge prior to render_book
rmd_files:
- index.Rmd # must include :)
#- text/00-abstract.Rmd
#- text/00-colophon.Rmd
#- text/00-acknowledge.Rmd
#- text/00-declaration.Rmd
#- text/00-preface.Rmd
- text/01-Intro.Rmd 
- text/02-IO.Rmd 
- text/03-Brainstem.Rmd 
- text/04-Cerebellum.Rmd 
- text/05-Behaviour.Rmd 
- text/References.Rmd
```

Comment: Great! The only quesiton I have is, do those Rmd's all have to have a top level header (#)? Could you have separate files for subsections within (i.e. 1.2 Some Topic which would be ## Some Topic)?

Comment: Not at all. They can be split however you want using the 'Merge and Knit' method, which works with the sub-directory method too, as long as you include `new_session: no` into `_bookdown.yml`, per https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/new-session.html

Comment: @TomKent if it answered your question, please mark it as accepted per https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers